# PHP loop through array of objects (JSON)

Tags: php, arrays, json

PHP receives this via AJAX in JSON format (let's call it `$json_string`):

`[{"pid":"284","qty":"1","sn":"12"},{"pid":"284","qty":"1","sn":"23"},{"pid":"276","qty":"1","sn":"34"},{"pid":"276","qty":"1","sn":"45"},{"pid":"276","qty":"1","sn":"56"},{"pid":"281","qty":"1","sn":"57"},{"pid":"281","qty":"1","sn":"67"},{"pid":"281","qty":"1","sn":"78"}]`

I wish to loop through the arrays, like so:

```
$out = '<table>';
$arr = json_decode($json_string);
foreach ($arr AS $row){
    $out .= '<tr><td>'.$row['pid'].'</td><td>'.$row['qty'].'</td><td>'.$row['sn'].'</td></tr>';
}
$out .= '</table>';
```

I am getting an error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Doesn't that mean that json_decode returns something that is NOT an array?

Comment: @ThomasKilian No, but `$arr = json_decode($json_string, true)` results in an associative array: `$pid = $arr['pid'];` -- whereas just `$arr = json_decode($json_string)` results in a simple array: `$pid = $arr[0];`  Depends on the data, not just the desired output. Above is assoc data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to force it to use an associative array:

```
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Or modify your code to use object notation for the objects:

```
foreach ($arr AS $row){
    $out .= '<tr><td>'.$row->pid.'</td><td>'.$row->qty.'</td><td>'.$row->sn.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Personally I prefer forcing it all to an associative array because its easier to work with, especially when you get into complex nested structures.

Comment: It's stated pretty clear in json_decode documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php